# How can I always keep the Desktop icons organised, and sorted by name?

Tags: unity, scripts, icons, desktop-icons

I would like to keep my Desktop always organised by name. How can I achieve this?

#### Desktop not organised by name:

[image]

#### Desktop after having organised by name:

[image]

Comment: If you fade the names, we cannot see exactly what is the organization rule :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Looks like his organization rule is to sort dirs first , then files. We also probably can guess it's alphabetical

Comment: Hi orschiro which of these two: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30927193#30927193

Comment: Apologies for that missing information! The desktop is organised alphabetically starting with folders from A to Z and then followed by files. Is that information sufficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Arrange desktop icons alphabetically by command

The script below will rearrange a desktop like:

[image]

...into an alphabetically ordered desktop like:

[image]

*Ordered:*

- directories first, then files
- from top to bottom, from left to right

#### Set the number of items vertically

Furthermore, you can set an arbitrary number of items vertically (rows); the horizontal spacing will be set automatically accordingly.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import math
import time

# set the size of the squares (indirectly, by setting n- rows)
rows = 10
# set x/y offset of the matrix if you want
x_offs = -15
y_offs = -30

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")

dt = get(["xdg-user-dir",  "DESKTOP"]).strip()         
# find size of the left screen
left = [int(n) for n in sum(
    [s.split("+")[0].split("x") for s in \
     get("xrandr").split() if "+0+" in s], [])]

# size of the squares (icon area)
sqr = int((left[1]/rows))

# number of cols, squares
cols = math.floor(left[0]/sqr)
n_sqrs = cols*rows

# define positions (matrix)
pos = list([[
    str(int((math.floor(n/rows)*sqr)+(sqr/2)+x_offs)),
    str(int(((n%rows)*sqr)+(sqr/2)+y_offs)),
    ] for n in range(n_sqrs)])

# list iconfiles, split into dirs and files, sort & combine
iconlist = [os.path.join(dt, item) for item in \
            sorted([item for item in os.listdir(dt) if not "~" in item])]
dirs = []; files = []
for it in iconlist:
    if os.path.isfile(it):
        files.append(it)
    else:
        dirs.append(it)
iconlist = dirs+files
# place icons in position(s)
for i, item in enumerate(iconlist):
    location = (",").join(pos[i])
    subprocess.call(["gvfs-set-attribute", "-t", "string", item,
                       'metadata::nautilus-icon-position', location])
# simulate F5 to refresh desktop, retry for max 20 secs if not in front
t = 0
while t < 40:
    w_id = [l.split()[-1] for l in get(["xprop", "-root"]).splitlines() \
        if "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW):" in l][0]
    if "desktop" in get(["xprop", "-id", w_id, "WM_CLASS"]):
        subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "key", "F5"])
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        t += 1
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `xdotool`:

   ```
     sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `arrange_dt.py`
3. Test- run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/arrange_dt.py
   ```

   ***within 20 seconds*** click on the desktop, your new arrangement will be applied. If you run the script from a shortcut, while the desktop is in front, the arrangement will be applied immediately. If the desktop is not frontmost, the script waits for max 20 seconds. If time exceeds, simply press <kbd>F5</kbd> to apply.
4. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/arrange_dt.py
   ```

#### Options

You can influence the arrangement of the icons in three ways:

1. set the size of the "tiles"

   ```py
   # set the size of the squares (indirectly, by setting n- rows)
   rows = 10
   ```

   This will set the (max) number of icons vertically. The *size* of the "tiles" will, be equal (x,y)
2. set the horizontal offset

   ```
   x_offs = -15
   ```

   This will set the x- deviation from the default position of the icon-matrix as a whole
3. Set the vertical offset

   ```
   y_offs = -30
   ```

   This will set the y- deviation from the default position of the icon-matrix

   An example, using:

   ```py
   # set the size of the squares (indirectly, by setting n- rows)
   rows = 6
   # set x/y offset of the matrix if you want
   x_offs = 50
   y_offs = 10
   ```

   [image]

#### Explanation

The explanation below is mostly an explanation on *the concept* rather than the coding

- To position the icons alphabetically, we first list the items on the desktop, using `python`'s `os.listdir(Desktop)`
- Then we split the files into two sublists; files/folders, and sort both lists, join them again, folders first.
- Then we create the matrix:

  - Since the number of rows is set in the head of the script, we divide the height of the screen by the number of rows. Thus we have the size of the "squares" the icons will be placed in (centered).
  - Since the icons are similarly spaced *horizontally*, we can then calculate the (max) number of columns by dividing the *width* of the screen by the width of the "squares" in which the icons will be placed (per icon), rounded down to the first integer below.
  - In the image below, these "virtual" squares are visible, the red dot is where the icon is placed.

    [image]
  - Then all we have to do is place the first icon on half of the size of a square, both horizontally and vertically.
  - To find the *x-position* of all other icons, we simply need to divide their *index* (starting with zero) by the number of rows, rounded down. The outcome will be added to the x position of the first icon (top left), for example:

    ```
    item 10 (index 9): 9/4 = 2,25, rounded down: 2
    x position = position of icon 0 + 2 x the width of a square

    item 17 (index 16): 16/4 = 4, rounded down: 4
    x position = position of icon 0 + 4 x the width of a square
    ```
  - To find the *y-position* of all other icons, we simply need the *remainder* of the index and the number of rows. The outcome x the width of a square will be added to the y position of the first icon (top left), for example:

    ```
    item 10 (index 9): 9%4 = 1
    y position = position of icon 0 + 1 x the height of a square

    item 17 (index 16): 16%4 = 0
    y position = position of icon 0 + 0 x the height of a square
    ```
- Subsequently, we place the icons on the desktop, using the command:

  ```
  gvfs-set-attribute <path_to_dir_or_file> metadata::nautilus-icon-position x,y
  ```
- Finally, we need to press <kbd>F5</kbd> *with the desktop in front*, to apply the changed layout (refresh the desktop). If that is the case, it will be done immediately. If not, the script re- trys during 20 seconds if the desktop is in front, virtually presses <kbd>F5</kbd> and breaks. If after 20 seconds the desktop *still* was not in front, you need to manually press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: What a fantastic and versatile script. Thank you so much, Jacob! :-)

Comment: @orschiro as always, your questions are somehow inspiring and great to work on :)

Comment: I just happen to stumble upon things that I think should be the default behaviour in Ubuntu. Happy to see there are greatly skilled people to make this reality!

Comment: Hey Jacob, I used the values `6 -50 -50` but three folders are slightly offset. Any ideas why? Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/XuGIiBT.png

Comment: Hi @orschiro That is because of the difference in width of the folder names. If the command cannot be executed because of that, it takes the first possible option. Better not set the offset too negative :)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the additional explanation! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired in part by the above question, I wrote `iconic` to solve this problem by letting you sort icons four different ways. Additionally it will:

- Define a grid to space icons closer or further apart
- Save icon desktop setup and restore it later for different setups home and work
- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.