# How can i keep icons aligned both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: unity, desktop-icons

[image: This is just freaking weird. "Keep Aligned" doesn't do anything.]

Is there ANY way to keep icons aligned both horizontally and vertically in a grid like Windows? This is just weird.

Comment: If you accept alphabetically as a side effect: http://askubuntu.com/questions/796802/how-can-i-always-keep-the-desktop-icons-organised-and-sorted-by-name/796996#796996 if not, I'd have to edit to remove part of the script :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm that is a wonderful script you wrote. +1 on it. Too bad it can't be modified to see where icons currently lie within virtual grid and then snap them to closest x,y spots (red dots).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `iconic` to solve this problem by letting you define a grid to evenly space icons. Additionally it will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.